# while parsing a pdf document using org.apache.pdfbox and java , '-' is converted as '?'

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
PDPDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(input);
PDFTextStripper stripper=new PDFTextStripper();
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
stripper.fixedCharWidth =5; 
String text= stripper.getText(pdfDoc);
```

When I observed the output for input string in the pdf file: `07‑Jul‑2014 / 7/ 2014`

Output of the above line is like this: `07?JUL?2014 /  7/ 2014`

Comment: Could you please upload your PDF somewhere, and also mention what version you are using? (Btw I did not downvote the question)

Comment: Is the character really a hyphen and not one of those long dashes that some applications use for visual purposes?

Comment: Please share the PDF for analysis. Most likely either the PDF simply contains wrong or incomplete information for text extraction or your output does not know the characters in question (as @JohnBickers implied).

Comment: The pdf file is my client's file and I can't share it, hope you understand my problem. pdfbox version I am using = 1.8.9.

Comment: Additional to the remark of John - please do mark, copy & paste in Adobe Reader. What do you get?

Comment: 07‑Jul‑2014 / 7/ 2014

Comment: As Tilman's suggestion, I copied it from PDF file to notepad++ , it is showing 07 followed a 'square as an image' . But when I copied to 'notepad'  , it is being shown as it is in the pdf document.

Comment: What you could also test, is to see how the command line utilities work on your file. Syntax is here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#extractText  (download the "pdfbox-app" from the download url). Then compare it with the output from the 2.0 version, that you can get here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: No Difference. I used beyond compare to compare the o/p generated by both versions 1.8.9 and 2.0 ; They are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here it is a work around (at least for me) : 
String DD_MM_YYYY_DATE_FORMAT_REGEX="[0-9]{1,2}(\\?)[a-zA-Z]{3}(\\?)[0-9]{4}";//string length=10
String DD_MMM_YYYY_DATE_FORMAT_REGEX="[0-9]{1,2}(\\?)[a-zA-Z]{3}(\\?)[0-9]{4}";//length=11

if(wordArray[index].substring(0,11).matches(DD_MMM_YYYY_DATE_FORMAT_REGEX))
{
        wordArray[index]=wordArray[index].replaceAll("\\?", "/");
}
                                if(wordArray[index].substring(0,10).matches(DD_MM_YYYY_DATE_FORMAT_REGEX))
{
    wordArray[index]=wordArray[index].replaceAll("\\?", "/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoding issue. Seeing as you won't share the PDF, I can only suggest trying the following:

```
PDFTextStripper stripper=new PDFTextStripper("UTF-8");
```